# Is it possible to normalize affine λ-calculus terms using PHOAS in Agda?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, coq, agda, lambda-calculus

In Agda, one can conveniently represent λ-terms using PHOAS:

```
data Term (V : Set) : Set where
  var : V → Term V
  abs : (V → Term V) → Term V
  app : Term V → Term V → Term V
```

That approach has several benefits over Bruijn indices, as explained in ["Parametric Higher-Order Abstract Syntax for Mechanized
Semantics"](http://adam.chlipala.net/papers/PhoasICFP08/PhoasICFP08.pdf). As far as I know, though, there can't be a `eval : ∀ {V} -> Term V -> Term V` function that, given a λ-term, returns its normal form - after all, Agda is total and the λ-calculus is not. But I wonder if it would be possible to write such `eval` function for affine λ-terms; i.e., those where bound variables occur at most once. That language is obviously total.

Comment: Presumably yes.  Translate your argument for why the language is "obviously total" into Agda and you will have your function.

Comment: @luqui but how? I honestly have no idea. I know how to write `subst` for that type from the paper; [here](https://lpaste.net/3842453789416095744) is an example of applying `id` to a constant. But writing a `eval : ∀ {V} → Term V → Term V` looks impossible. Note `apply : Term V -> V -> Term V`, so, `eval (app f x) = subst (apply f x)` would not be typeable because `x : V` instead of `Term V`. I guess I'd need a whole new way to write `eval`, but I'm not sure what that'd be like.

Comment: @MaiaVictor I would first just consider normalization for the first-order syntax, you can always go to and from PHOAS (although this may require to postulate some parametricity theorems).

Comment: @AndrásKovács normalization for the first-order syntax is itself something I didn't manage to do, but since I'm more interested in PHOAS I decided to keep the question smaller by just asking about it. Is there any obvious way to normalize the first-order syntax? My idea was to write `eval : Nat -> Term -> Term` where the `Nat` is the size of the term; like [this](https://lpaste.net/989790593641086976). But I'm not sure (haven't actually thought yet) how to prove that it actually returns the normal form. That's probably silly anyway so I wonder if you know / could link a better way to do it?

Comment: I'm not sure PHOAS is ideal for this job. I'd want a representation that more explicitly witnesses affinity. Nice problem.

Comment: You might try first converting the lambda expression to a combinator expression with an “abstraction algorithm” using only Bxyz=x(yz), Cxyz=xzy, Kxy=x, Ix=x—the result is guaranteed by construction to be affine, so it might be easier to formulate the proof that evaluation is terminating

Comment: At least two strategies occur to me. One is to exploit the fact that every beta reduction guarantees a net loss of at least one lambda. The other (which I think I prefer) is to show that every affine lambda term has a simple type.